# ActivityCompat.requestPermissions does not show prompt when requesting ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

Tags: java, android, permissions

in MainActivity i request permission :

for api >=29

**this code don't show promt when i request permissions**

```
public boolean RequestPermissions(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {// api 29++
                final String[] PERMISSIONS_API_Q = {
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
        };

        if (    checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
               checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        )
        {//Permissions Granted
            GB.LOG("Permissions is granted");
            getAndroidId();// getting device information
            GB.isPermissionsGranted = true;
            if(MainFragment.MainHandler!=null){
                MainFragment.MainHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            }
            LoadFoldersPath();
            if(GB.CanManualMode){
                CanConfig cc = new CanConfig();
                cc.execute();
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {//Permissions is revoked 
            GB.LOG("Permissions is revoked");
            Dialogs LocationInfoDialog = new Dialogs(MainActivity.this);
            View.OnClickListener onClickListener= v -> {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_API_Q, REQUEST); //here is permission request 
                GB.isPermissionsGranted = false;
            };
            LocationInfoDialog.GPSUsageInBackGroundInfo(onClickListener);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**when i remove this lines**

```
>     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
>     checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) ==
>     PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

**This code works fine**

```
public boolean RequestPermissions(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {// api 29++
                final String[] PERMISSIONS_API_Q = {
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        };

        if (    checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
               checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                
        )
        {//Permissions Granted
            GB.LOG("Permissions is granted");
            getAndroidId();// getting device information
            GB.isPermissionsGranted = true;
            if(MainFragment.MainHandler!=null){
                MainFragment.MainHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            }
            LoadFoldersPath();
            if(GB.CanManualMode){
                CanConfig cc = new CanConfig();
                cc.execute();
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {//Permissions is revoked 
            GB.LOG("Permissions is revoked");
            Dialogs LocationInfoDialog = new Dialogs(MainActivity.this);
            View.OnClickListener onClickListener= v -> {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_API_Q, REQUEST); //here is permission request 
                GB.isPermissionsGranted = false;
            };
            LocationInfoDialog.GPSUsageInBackGroundInfo(onClickListener);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

you can even compare this two codes here to see difference https://text-compare.com/

**but if i remove ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION from request everything works fine, where is problem ?**

Comment: `when requesting list of permission` You are not requesting with a list of permissions but check them one by one. Further it is possible to request a list of permissions. Further it is unclear about which prompt you are talking as checking for a permission would not cause a prompt.

Comment: `but if i remove ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION from request` We dont see how you request that permission. We only see that you check it in that if statement. It is unclear where you are removing things.

Comment: `where is problem ?` Please describe your problem better.

Comment: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_API_Q, REQUEST); here is line where i request permissions it's inside code //Permissions is revoked

Comment: And you think we know what that call would do? In which way? And can you react to the point to my comments as i got no answers and i still dont know the problem.

Comment: @blackapps This line requesting permission  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_API_Q, REQUEST) inside this string is permission that i request PERMISSIONS_API_Q

Comment: It is unclear to me if removing the check would change things or removing that permission from requests would change things. And are you telling that                 checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
 always is false?

Comment: I suggest you do a test where you remove all the other permissions and only experiment with ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION.

Comment: i get no promt for permission if this two lines are included

Comment: Yes we knew already. Why are you telling again? We still dont know how a prompt would look like asking so many permissions at one time. And why dont you comment on the things i said/asked?

Comment: @blackapps is ask permission one by one in one dialog

Comment: Is it? ActivityCompat.requestPermissions handles them all at once as you give it that array PERMISSIONS_API_Q. So all at once i would say. Repeat: `We still dont know how a prompt would look like asking so many permissions at one time.`.

Comment: @blackapps  just check it and you will see how it look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution  `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` can be requested only after when you already received `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission

Here is result

```
    private static final int REQUEST = 1;

    public boolean RequestPermissions() {
    final String[] PERMISSIONS_API_M = {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {

            if (!(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                final String[] PERMISSIONS_API_Q = {
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                };
                Dialogs AccessBackGroundDialog = new Dialogs(MainActivity.this);
                View.OnClickListener onClickListener = v -> {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_API_Q, REQUEST);
                };
                AccessBackGroundDialog.GPSUsageInBackGroundInfo(onClickListener, true);
                return false;
            }
            GB.LOG("Permissions is granted");
            getAndroidId();// getting device information
            GB.isPermissionsGranted = true;
            if (MainFragment.MainHandler != null) {
                MainFragment.MainHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            }
            LoadFoldersPath();
            if (GB.CanManualMode) {
                CanConfig cc = new CanConfig();
                cc.execute();
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            GB.LOG("Permissions is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_API_M, REQUEST);
            GB.isPermissionsGranted = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we request for both `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` at a time in an array?

Comment: no, when requested both i don't get request prompt , so i request first `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` then if  request successul do next request  `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`

Comment: To deal with the ordering, rationales, permanent denial and other edgecases I would like to promote my own library that I have been working for quite some time. It is inspired by how Google Fit is doing it. https://github.com/warting/permissions-ui I hope someone find it useful.